# using SIMD for conversion of ASCII string to floating point

Tags: floating-point, x86, vectorization, simd, floating-point-conversion

Is it possible to improve runtime speed for convertion of big inputs of floating point numbers in string representation ([example of format](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/workbench/qi/real_parser.cpp)) into the `float`s/`double`s/`long double`s (in terms of *C*)?

Can I use string SSE/AVX/AVX2/AVX512 instructions (or any other) to create a kind of lookup table to speedup conversion on some steps? Assume all the `xmm`/`ymm`/`zmm` registers can be used to store a lookup table.

Comment: zero padded numbers would be easier, otherwise lining them in SIMD would take extra cycles before multiplying with 10,100,1000,..

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I need all this formats: "1234", "-1.2e3", "0.1", "-1.2e-3", "-.2e3", "-2e6", "1.2345e5", "-5.7222349715140557e+307", "2.0332938517515416e-308".

Comment: @Orient, String instruction are abandoned since SSE4.2.You have the chance to use VEX.128 instructions for this.

Comment: Please simplify and narrow the question to a section of your program.

Comment: @FackedDeveloper It is general question about possibility to use advanced instruction sets to improve existent solutions of old general problem, which arised here and there. Inherently it is not narrow question by definition.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use binary representation? SIMD cannot cure a flawed design or help bandwidth limited code.

Comment: @Holmz Why me? It is general task - to parse a string containing the numbers in textual form. I even curious why there is no hardware support for such common operation. A quadrillions of kWh wasted on it.

Comment: @Orient, So a general answer to this question is yes you can use SIMDization for this general task. There are many general instructions which might be useful such as blend, aligner, perm, etc.